# Why are old questions not closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, old-questions

Some questions have date asked as far back as 7 years ago!! Why are these questions not closed so as not to appear in latest questions list?

Comment: If they're showing up in "latest questions list", then you're probably looking at "active" questions and see an old question that was edited/answered.

Comment: @KevinB Or you've just gone pretty far beyond the first page ;)

Comment: Before more down votes are added to the question, let me rephrase the question to include "Old questions, after getting  the acceptable or accepted answer status, should be moved to Archived questions list after some cool off period".

The question and the answer anyway shows up on Google searches due to the tags.

Comment: we have an archived questions list?

Comment: but... i've commented twice. make that three times

Comment: Why archive them? If you want to see something changed on the site, 1) show us the problem, and make sure you give evidence of it (provided there actually is a problem) and 2) tell us _why your suggestion is good._ What benefit is there to archiving the questions after some time, when there's a chance under our system for them to get a better/updated answer? What makes archiving them correct versus leaving them open to new answers if updates occur to the relevant technologies?

Comment: And pro-tip: Putting a comment about downvotes or asking for downvotes to stop or asking for comments with downvotes in your question is a sure-fire way to get more downvotes, usually still without comment.

Comment: Not archiving for archiving sake but archive it so that the old questions can be categorized as 'dated'.

For instance, a question on a Scrum practice dated 7 years ago would obviously be not as relevant today but it shows up against a question asked a month ago under the 'Related' sidebar.

Comment: And then you have cases where a question asked 7+ years ago IS still very relevant to today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: It shows up there _because_ it's related, regardless of the time asked. It's not labelled _"Recent Related Questions"_ or anything like that, after all. I've come over old questions a number of times that have indeed answered my question, either because the answer was still relevant or because a new answer with the more recent relevant solution was posted.

Comment: Changing the entire meaning of your question after getting three answers responding to the original version doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Why not post a new question with the "archive" proposal?

Comment: Changed the entire meaning of the question after seeing the response was not what I was looking for. 

Sure will post a new question with the archive proposal.

Comment: Well, none of the answers before Patrick's correspond whatsoever if the question isn't asking about things being "closed".

Comment: Well, shall I delete this question?

Answer (score 10):

They're not closed because they don't meet any closure criteria.  If you see an open question that you feel merits closure, then flag it for closure for the appropriate reason.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you misunderstand the term's use here. "Closed" on Stack Exchange means "not answerable within the topical scope  of the site". This can be because the question is simply not about the right subject matter, or because it's faulty in some way.

"Closed" doesn't mean "solved", or "completed", or anything like that. So questions don't get closed just because of age. Neither do they get closed because they're answered. (We use the "accepted answer" feature for that.)

We are open to the possibility that someone else may come along and post an answer that supersedes existing answers in some way.

Answer (score 5):

A lot can change, in a week, a month, a year. New technology or new insights can blow away previous answers by just being so much better. The question can still be very valid and useful to others.

Why wouldn't we give the question asker and other viewers the ability to benefit from new answers, additional comments or edits that make the post better?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the idea seems to be not to bother with old questions that aren't causing a problem. I personally don't like this because it creates bad audits and people complain here on meta. It would be better to be proactive.

If you see a question that should be closed by today's standards, flag it (then close vote it after getting enough rep).

Note that not everything from the dawn of SO is bad. There are a number of questions that are a bit broad, but otherwise useful because they have great answers.